# Is there a way to add a track to an existing playlist in the new spotify API since 1.0

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

The old spotify API provided the playlist.add(track) [method](http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/c49e02a392.html),
whereas i can not find this method in the [new 1.0 API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/api/api-models-playlist.html)

Is there a possible walkaround to add a track to an existing playlist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a track to an existing playlist like so. Remember that you'll need to load tracks first, otherwise the tracks won't be on the playlist object.

```
require(['$api/models'], function(models) {
    models.Playlist.fromURI('spotify:user:thelinmichael:playlist:4GiqW15bSO7K6MLFVRVh4z').load('tracks').done(function(playlist) {
        track = models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:3fllpI9uZKkdy3NJS0J1oV");
        playlist.tracks.add(track);
    }); 
});
```

Read more about the Collection class [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/api/api-models-collection.html).